# Selenium python return history 302

Tags: python, selenium, unauthorized

I got a problem when trying scrape content from a website by trying access api

I use this code to login the page

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
#options.add_argument("--headless") # Runs Chrome in headless mode.
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox') # Bypass OS security model
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')  # applicable to windows os only
options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Defaul") #Path to your chrome profile
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="\\chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
#driver=webdriver.Chrome()
site="https:xxxxxx"
# call open browser function
# Github credentials
username = "username"

password = "password"

# head to github login page
driver.get(site)
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element_by_id("username").send_keys(username)
time.sleep(20)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element_by_id("password").send_keys(password)
time.sleep(25)
# click login button
driver.find_element_by_id("btnLogin").click()
```

In login page I see a login form, with value is changing everytime I log in

```
 id="FormLogin" method="post" style="margin-top: 1%;"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

After login page, It return an otp

```
otp="xxxxxx"
driver.find_element_by_id("otp").send_keys(otp)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div/div/button[1]").click()
```

After login the page, I can search, and see results, but whenever I try to use api to scrape the results it return none

I try to save my session

```
s = requests.Session()
# Set correct user agent
selenium_user_agent = driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")
s.headers.update({"user-agent": selenium_user_agent})

for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'], domain=cookie['domain'])
```

then, using this code to scrape content

```
import requests
base_url = 'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxPageNumber=1&CurrentSystemDate=12/08/2022&X-Requested-With=XMLHttpRequest'

response = s.get(base_url)
print(response.status_code) #it returns 200
print(response.history)  #it returns 302
print(response.content) # It returns login page content
```

If I pass the API in browser, it return login page, and force me logout

```
<form action="/Logout" method="get">
 <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="y_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
```

I think that the page saved token or session when I login. If I scrape content by api, my token or session is empty so it returns login page content
Please help me to solve the issue
Thanks for reading and helping me

Answer (score 0):

You may specify headers in get(), and set the token value in headers. It is better to open the base_url in browser and trace the request to see its payload format including headers so you can mimic it.

If the base_url is not an API url, an alternative is to locate a high level html element of the page and get its html content directly.